How can I display an image in a child process in python?
I'm working on optics characterization, for which I need to display an image and take a picture at the same time. To do this, I create a child process that handles the display and take the picture in the main process.
This is the function that does the displaying:
def display(image, width, height, screen_id = 1):
    print('displaying image...')
    screen = screeninfo.get_monitors()[screen_id]
    window_name = 'projector'
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.moveWindow(window_name, screen.x - 1, screen.y - 1)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                          cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    image = np.uint8(image)
    cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

which is called as follows in main:
SLMprocess = Process(target=SLM.display, args=(deltaMap, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0))
SLMprocess.start()

When I call this function in the main process, it works like a charm, but in the child process it fails silently.
By using prints, I was able to find that it gets lost at the cv2.namedWindow(...) line. Apparently GUI stuff is expected to be handled in main, but in my case I don't see how I could do this, as it would block the execution of the function that takes the picture.
Any idea of how to correct this?

See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

why do you scatter your data across processes? what reason would you have to not do the GUI in the same process? -- opencv is not a gui library.

@ChristophRackwitz I have a camera connected to the machine, with which I need to take a snapshot while displaying. If I display in the main process, everything stops until I close the image, which defeats the whole purpose. The other option would be to take the picture in the child process with a delay, but that seems very clumsy...

no that's wrong. it is very much possible, and recommended, to keep all these tasks in one process. waitKey(0) isnt't he only way to call waitKey. [mre] required.

The problem is I was trying to drive a camera that had bee initialized in the main process from a child process. When displaying and driving the camera, I wasn't paying attention to the handles. Changing my functions to initialize everything on each call and close everything properly at the end solved the problem.
